maui: collectionview insivible layouts still take up space
in my collection view i am displaying the stacklayout at the bottom:
<CollectionView  SelectionMode="Single"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding WifiHotSpots}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:WifiSelectionModel">
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ClickCommand, Source={x:Reference WifiPageViewPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsActive}" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Grey">
                    <Label Text="Network pass:"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Entry IsPassword="True" Text="{Binding NetworkPass}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Button Command="{Binding BindingContext.ConnectCommand, Source={x:Reference WifiPageViewPage}}" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" Text="connect"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

The IsVisible prop is set to a binding. I set it to true or false from mvvm code.
It works (kinda) as layouts pop in and out but always take up the space.
What could this be?
Thank you!

Ways to do it:

Use VerticalStackLayout

 <VerticalStackLayout>
   <SomeView IsVisble="{Binding SomeProperty}"..
   <AnotherView>

The upper view will push everything down when visible, and pull it up, when not.

Use Grid:

  <Grid RowDefinitions "*,Auto"
    <SomeView IsVisible="SomeProperty" Grid.Row="1"..
    <AnotherView>

At the bottom of the page, you will see a row with your view, that will be pushing everything up when visible, and the other view will be taking all the space when not.
Notice how I do not specify "heights" anywhere.
This part from your code will take 50 from your view, no matter the visibility of contained views.
  <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>


I advise you to switch your Grid with VerticalStackLayout before you attempt the Grid way. (Meaning go with first solution)

There's an issue with IsVisible, you can set it to Collapsed through Xaml only at this moment, even though Microsoft says that setting it to false will not preserve the space.
Try this:
    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsActive}" HeightRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=-1,Default=1}" ...

Or these together:
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsActive}" HeightRequest="50" .../>


hello, unfortunately, collpased doesnt exist and the other two solutions didnt fix it

Are you targeting. net8 ? I will test it later and update you
